# AngularJS ng-repeat with external image source not updating view with images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've run into an issue building a new website where I'm pulling a get request from an external API that contains an image "ID".  This image ID can be accessed by going to https://externalsite.com/getimage/id_width.png (width is variable, 128, 256, 512, etc.)

Once the get request is complete, it populates my ng-src with the correct links.  The problem is that the images never actually show up.  I can go into the developer tools and see that the source is correct but the image doesn't display on the page.  If I do **NOT** use ng-repeat, the images show up just fine and the page behaves as expected.  If I use ng-repeat, the images never show up in the view but if you look at the actual image tag, the source is set properly.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="KillCtrl" class="isotope-container row grid-space-20">
    <div ng-repeat="kill in kills" class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 isotope-item web-design">
        <div class="image-box">
            <div class="overlay-container">
                <img ng-src="{{kill.shipimage}}" alt="Cover Image">
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('disconnectEVE', [])
.config([
'$compileProvider',
function( $compileProvider )
{
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
}
]);

app.factory('killfactory', function ($http, $q) {
var factory = {};
factory.getlist = function(){
    return $http.get('https://zkillboard.com/api/corporationID/98379655/pastSeconds/86400/',{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}).
    success(function(data){
        console.log("great success!");
        return data;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(headers);
        console.log(config);
        return data;
    });
}
return factory;
});

app.controller('KillCtrl', function($scope, $http, killfactory) {

killfactory.getlist().success(function(data){
    $scope.kills = data;
    angular.forEach($scope.kills, function(kill){
            kill.shipimage = "https://image.eveonline.com/Render/" + kill.victim.shipTypeID + "_256.png";
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.kills));
});
$scope.message = "Hello!";
$scope.victim = "victim1";
});
```

RETURN:

for some reason I can't get this to format as code, this is a partial return due to the large nature of these returns.

> {"killID":"46162609","solarSystemID":"30003079","killTime":"2015-04-23 05:07:00","moonID":"0","victim":{"shipTypeID":"29988","damageTaken":"27942","factionName":"","factionID":"0","allianceName":"That Escalated Quickly.","allianceID":"99003940","corporationName":"The Echelon Phoenix","corporationID":"98342213","characterName":"Ionic Freeze","characterID":"93593140"

I'm pretty new to Angular so I get the feeling I'm doing the factory wrong which is causing an issue with bi-directional databinding not updating the view.  I've searched for a lot of hours and re-implemented this a good 2-3 times in different ways and can't seem to get these images to show up.  Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try $scope.apply() after your forEach

Comment: Looks ok [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/g28iWVzfpAXwvve0wQXa?p=preview). Might be some issues with CSS.

Comment: After adding $scope.$apply(); after the forEach loop I get a really ugly error.

Comment: Yauheni - do you have any ideas of what could cause this in CSS?  I looked through CSS to see if something pops out but I can't see anything that would affect the images only when they are ng-repeat'ed.  Thanks!

Another strange thing I've noticed is that every once in a while the page will actually load properly.  Upon reloading the page it always breaks.  This is about a 1/100 occurrence :(.

Comment: Two questions: What is the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.kills))` in the browser console? and secondly, did you right-click the image and check source property in your browser after it loads, what does it say?

Comment: I'll update on the output tomorrow, for some reason the zkillboard API has started returning CORS errors to me.  If I stop hitting it for a while with requests it will normally start working again.

Prahlad - Because the image doesn't load properly, it isn't displaying on the screen which makes it very difficult to right-click on.  I can inspect it with chrome's developer tools and see the correct source property is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the culprit was an isotope setting.  The setting for .isotope-container called overflow and set to value hidden was causing the updated images to not be rendered.  Once I disabled that setting the images started working as they were supposed to.  I will start looking into the angular-isotope directive so that I can stop using isotope all by itself.  Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting image urls before you set $scope.kills

```
app.controller('KillCtrl', function($scope, $http, killfactory) {

    killfactory.getlist().success(function(data){
       var kills = data;
       angular.forEach(kills, function(kill){
           kill.shipimage = "https://image.eveonline.com/Render/" + kill.victim.shipTypeID + "_256.png";
       });
       $scope.kills = kills;
       console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.kills));

       $scope.message = "Hello!";
       $scope.victim = "victim1";
    });
});
```

This will ensure that image path is set before scope value is set. Also one thing to do is make sure that img tag is self-closed so it looks like `<img ... />`, this is because scopes generated by ng-repeat may leak if not closed properly.

Comment: I gave this a shot but am still experiencing the same behavior.  If you want to see the website in action go to:
http://disconnect.cloudviewhost.com

I'm logging the json in the console.

Thank you!